# Java Expression Evaluation

Tags: java

Consider the java code below. The output which i got is written after the `//`

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x=10;
        System.out.println("X="+10 == "X="+10); // TRUE
        System.out.println("X="+x == "X="+x);   // FALSE
    }
}
```

In both the lines String concatenation is going to happen but how the output is different?

Comment: Because the first one is evaluated at compile time, so the strings got pooled. Duplicate.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite fascinated by this. Obviously, java does not intern string literals only, but it interns **any** literal. It even 'works' for `"X="+012` or `"X="+0b1010` (just tested it).

Comment: @Izruo It interns any *compile-time* string literal.

Comment: Could you please eleborate the both statement. I didn't get. Thanks in advance

Comment: `"X="+10` can be evaluated at compile time. `"X="+x` cannot.

Comment: @user207421 sorry to be pedantic, but an int literal concatenated with a string literal isn't a [string literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5): it's a ["constant expression of type `String`"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), which is guaranteed to be interned.